# Python - как загрузить куки из файла в session?

Tags: python

Подскажите как загрузить куки из файла в session = requests.Session()
Куки в таком формате приложил в фото. Или может как то нужно конвертировать в стиль requests?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот вам скриншот ссылки с решением вашей задачи: https://imgur.com/a/WmPPlDt

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: куки в requests в виде словаря у вас какая то каша на скриншоте.

Comment: @СергейШашко это не каша, а формат кук Mozilla

Comment: так переведите для понимания

Comment: Так мне и нужно перевести их как то в куки в requests

Comment: как вы думаете на ващем скриншоте есть кукис? приведите пример из скриншота

Comment: дело в том что эти куки в зеннопостер подгружаю и нормально заходит в аккаунт, а вот в requests не получается их загрузить, поэтому и спрашиваю кто может помочь с этим и реально ли?